# Minecraft failing to login "Cannot connect to our servers"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, minecraft-launcher

When I try to log into Minecraft, I keep getting this error message:

> Sorry we couldn't connect to our servers. Make sure that you are online
>   and that Minecraft is not blocked.
>
> SocketTimeoutException:connect timed out

I'm currently using the launcher 1.6.11

Comment: just for curiosity, can you go to your `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center` and on the left side under your network SSID it should say either Private Network or Public Network. Which does yours say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, if you are running Windows, that Firewall isn't blocking Minecraft. Also disable your virus protection software or add Java as an exception. But if you are on Mac, I'm not your guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try redownloading the launcher and if you use wifi disconnect and reconnect, if it persists get on another computer (if you can) and contact mojang support.